# how to run a php script daily with the cron job on Ubuntu os

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-12.04, cron

command to runI am using ubuntu 12 and lamp server . I want to run a php script after every 1 hour . i have create a crontab to execute this and if i check my cron list with command crontab -l it is showing like this

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cronjobs/cron1.php

# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

this is my php script

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cronjobs/cron1.php
```

but it is not executing

how can i check why it is not working , please help

Comment: sorry but it is not working for me

Answer (score 10):

You can use crontab to add/remove/edit cronjobs.

Hit Alt+Ctrl+T to open terminal.

First make sure the script is executable by running:

```
chmod +x YOURSCRIPT
```

Then run the following command to add your cronjob:

```
crontab -e
```

Add your cronjob like this:

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php path/of/php/file
```

That's it!

Your can check the current user's crontab entries by running:

```
crontab -l
```

For more information about crontab run:

```
crontab --help
```

OR

```
man crontab
```

Comment: i am using the same . Do you know how can i run this from terminal just for a check like this ?? "sudo 0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php path/of/php/file"

Comment: No you can not run as you want. Did you check that it is running in browser and give desired result?

Comment: yes it is running from browser. is there a way to run it from command line??? it is also working if i use command "php5 -q /var/www/cronjobs/cron1.php" from command line

Comment: it is working i i run this "php5 -q /var/www/cronjobs/cron1.php"

Comment: I think you have to use this for run php script:

0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php php5 path/of/php/file

also you can see extra from here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/417122/running-php-cron-job-with-arguments

Answer (score 7):

To find out what is wrong with your cron you can type the following command in your terminal:

```
grep -i "cron1.php" /var/log/syslog
```

The syslog contains all log of crons.

Try run the code  `/usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cronjobs/cron1.php` on terminal to check if there are errors.

You can also redirect all errors to a file:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cronjobs/cron1.php 2> /tmp/errorCron1.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

## Make Script File /etc/scripts/cron.sh with contain

```
cd /var/www/

/usr/bin/php cron.php
```

## Save it then

```
chmod +x cron.sh
```

## then go on /etc/crontab

```
15 15 * * * root /etc/scripts/cron.sh
```

save it 
and wait

Answer (score 3):

This is the description of crontab arguments

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
0        2          12             *                *            /usr/bin/find
```

To Run your script every hour use below crontab entry.

```
0 */1 * * * /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cronjobs/cron1.php
```

This way your script will start executing every hour.