# how to run cronjob in hosting

Tags: php, cron

I have created a script that gets all the sales from database and compares if the days left in sale is in `negative` or `less than 0.2` then it would update it's `status` column as `Inactive`. It is running great!

```
<?php
include_once '../includes/db_connect.php';
$stmtgetallsales = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM store_sales");
$stmtgetallsales->execute();
$getallsales = $stmtgetallsales->get_result();
$stmtgetallsales->close();

while ($allsales = $getallsales->fetch_assoc()) {
    $db_date =  join('-',array_reverse(explode('-',$allsales['sale_till'])))." ".$allsales['created_time'];
    $check = get_date($db_date);

    if ($check < 0 || $check <= 0.2) {
        $stmtupdatesale = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE store_sales SET status='Inactive' WHERE sale_id = ?");
        $stmtupdatesale->bind_param("i", $allsales['sale_id']);
        $stmtupdatesale->execute();
        $stmtupdatesale->close();
    }
}
function get_date($old) {
    $offset=5*60*60;
    $timeFormat="H:i";
    $time=gmdate($timeFormat, time()+$offset);
    $now = date("Y-m-d");

    $dateOldd = $now." ".$time;

    $dateCurrent = new DateTime($dateOldd);
    $dateNew = new DateTime($old);

    $difference_in_seconds = $dateNew->getTimestamp() - $dateCurrent->getTimestamp();

    return $total_difference_in_days = $difference_in_seconds / 86400;
}

?>
```

Now I have to run this script in my hosting. I have this panel in front of me

[panel of cronjob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc831.png)

I am going to run this script `once per hour every 24 hours every day`

What settings should I put and what to write in `Command` line.

I am new to cronjob. THank you for help!

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235524/how-to-run-a-php-script-daily-with-the-cron-job-on-ubuntu-os

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run a php script daily with the cron job on Ubuntu os](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235524/how-to-run-a-php-script-daily-with-the-cron-job-on-ubuntu-os)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if php 5.6

`/opt/php56/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron.php`